# session is not saved for some variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I have 2 pages in the website; one gets  `username` from the URL, puts it into `$_SESSION` and displays a list of the groups this user belongs to.

When the user chooses a group, the site goes to the next page (the `group.php` page) and it gives the group name in its URL for it to be used in the group page.

In the group page there is a form to send messages that are to be displayed in the group page (kindda like a Facebook wall, I guess).

Here's the problem:
In the group list page `username` is sent into the session;
After the group name is picked-up by the group page I sent it into a session as well,
but for some reason when the page gets to the `if(isset($_POST['texts']))` part- it remembers the username but not the groupname.

Any idea why is that?
Following is the code for the group page.

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    include_once("../connect.php");
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $uid = $row['id'];
        }

    if(isset($_GET['groupname'])) {
        $groupname = $_GET['groupname'];    
    }

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM groups WHERE groupname='$groupname'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $gid = $row['id'];
        }

    $_SESSION['groupname'] = $groupname;
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action=
    <?php
    echo "'group.php?id=" . $gid . "'";
    ?> method="post" name="newtext">
        <textarea name="texts" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="subtext" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <?php
    //add text message
    if(isset($_POST['texts'])){
        $texts = $_POST['texts'];

        if($texts == "") {
            echo "<script>alert('no message writen')</script>"; 
        }else{
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO texts (`sender`, `sent`, `group`, `text`)
                        VALUES ('$uid', now(), '$gid', '$texts');");
            echo "<script>alert('message recieved!')</script>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You're doing `group.php?id` shouldn't that be `group.php?groupname`?

Comment: This  should be wrapped in quotes `action="<?php echo "'group.php?id=" . $gid . "'"; ?>"` also.

Comment: you are using saving groupname in session or in url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in that case the $_GET['groupname'] does not exist any more.

```
echo "'group.php?id=" . $gid . "'";
```

I dont see you using $_GET['id'] any place, so the action should be

*group.php?groupname=GROUPNAME_HERE*
 instead of *group.php?id=1*

This should work:

```
<form action="group.php?groupname=<?php echo $groupname; ?>" method="post" name="newtext">
```

I would also add an else statement here to decide what to do if the variable does not exist.

```
if(isset($_GET['groupname'])) {
    $groupname = $_GET['groupname'];    
}
```

Comment: Ended up telling the page to check both options